# How to sumarize correctly as “Order Time” + “leave Time” - mysql (add Hours not seconds)

Tags: mysql, datetime, sum, time-format

In mysql database i've created leave table:

```
+--------+---------+---------+-------------+---------+--------------------------
|ID_LEAVE|ID_WORKER| FNAME | LNAME | BEGIN_DATE         | END_DATE             | 
+--------+---------+---------+---------+------------+--------------------+------
| 1      |   1     | ALAN  | MAX   |2019-03-19 07:00:00 |2019-03-20 15:00:00   | 
| 2      |   1     | ALAN  | MAX   |2019-03-21 07:00:00 |2019-03-21 15:00:00   |
+--------+---------+---------+----------------------+---------------------------
```

"Workers Table"

```
+----------+---------+---------+
|ID_WORKER |  FNAME  | LNAME   |
+----------+---------+----------
| 1        |  ALAN   |  MAX    |
| 2        |  MARK   |  DARK   |
+----------+---------+---------+
```

"Orders" Table:

```
+----------+--------------+---------------+
|ID_ORDER  |  DESC_ORDER  | NUMBER_ORDER  |
+----------+--------------+---------------+
| 20       |  TEST        |  TEST         |
+----------+--------------+---------------+
```

"Order_status" Table:

```
+----------+---------+---------+---------------------+-------------------+------------+
| Id_status|ID_WORKER| ID_ORDER| BEGIN_DATE          | END_DATE          | ORDER_DONE |
+----------+---------+---------+----------+------------+---------+--------------------+
| 30       |   1     |    20   |2019-03-18 06:50:35  |2019-03-18 15:21:32|  NO        |
| 31       |   1     |    20   |2019-03-20 06:44:12  |2019-03-20 15:11:23|  NO        |
| 32       |   1     |    20   |2019-03-22 06:50:20  |2019-03-22 12:22:33|  YES       |
| 33       |   2     |    20   |2019-03-18 06:45:11  |2019-03-18 15:14:45|  NO        |
| 34       |   2     |    20   |2019-03-20 06:50:22  |2019-03-20 15:10:32|  NO        |
| 35       |   2     |    20   |2019-03-22 06:54:11  |2019-03-22 11:23:45|  YES       |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+
```

What i've done:

I can to sumarize "total time" of each other workers (in order_status table) on the order including with sumarizing "leave time" from Leave table and sumarizing "Order time" + "leave time" too (partly). I have selected workers (LNAME, FNAME) orders (DESC_ORDER and NUMBER_ORDER) and "TOTAL TIME" on order from each other workers correctly too. I wrote the mysql command in below:

```
SELECT workers.fname, 
       workers.lname, 
       order_statusAgg.number_order,
       workers.id_worker,
       order_statusAgg.desc_order, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(order_statusAgg.stime)) AS 'ORDER TIME', 
       IFNULL(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(leaveAgg.vtime)),'00:00:00') AS 'LEAVE TIME'
       time_format(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(order_statusAgg.stime)) +  IFNULL(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(leaveAgg.vtime)),'00:00:00'), '%H:%i:%s') AS 'TOTAL TIME'
FROM   workers 
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT leave.id_worker, time_format(SUM((datediff(leave.end_date, leave.begin_date) + 1) * (time(leave.end_date) - time(leave.begin_date))), '%H:%i:%s') AS vtime 
FROM leave
GROUP BY leave.id_worker 
) leaveAgg
               ON leaveAgg.id_worker = workers.id_worker
       LEFT JOIN (
SELECT order_status.id_worker, orders.number_order, orders.desc_order, SUM((Time_to_sec(order_status.end_date) - 
                       Time_to_sec(order_status.begin_date))) AS stime
FROM order_status
           INNER JOIN orders 
               ON orders.id_order = order_status.id_order
GROUP BY order_status.id_worker
) order_statusAgg
               ON workers.id_worker = order_statusAgg.id_worker 

WHERE  order_statusAgg.number_order LIKE 'TEST'
GROUP BY workers.id_worker
```

Then i get the result:

```
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
|  FNAME  | LNAME   |  NUMBER_ORDER | DESC_ORDER | ORDER TIME | LEAVE_TIME   | TOTAL TIME|
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
|  ALAN   |  MARK   | TEST          | TEST       | 22:30:21   |   24:00:00   |  22:30:45 |
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
|  MARK   |  GREEN  | TEST          | TEST       | 21:19:18   |   00:00:00   |  21:19:18 |
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
```

But on the other hand this query has added only 24 seconds not 24 hours
Because maybe of this line of query:

```
time_format(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(order_statusAgg.stime)) +  IFNULL(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(leaveAgg.vtime)),'00:00:00'), '%H:%i:%s') AS 'TOTAL TIME'
```

that should be:

```
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
|  FNAME  | LNAME   |  NUMBER_ORDER | DESC_ORDER | ORDER TIME | LEAVE_TIME   | TOTAL TIME|
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
|  ALAN   |  MARK   | TEST          | TEST       | 22:30:21   |   24:00:00   |  46:30:21 |
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
|  MARK   |  GREEN  | TEST          | TEST       | 21:19:18   |   00:00:00   |  21:19:18 |
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
```

Because of for example:
ALAN MARK for TEST order: Total time = Order time + leave time
Total time = 22:30:21 + 24:00:00 = 46:30:21

Can someone show what kind of query should i write it? Any ideas? Thank you for any help or advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said Total time = Order time + leave time Total time = 22:30:21 + 24:00:00 = 46:30:21

so one way to solve this problem is use [addtime](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-addtime-function.php) function

```
ADDTIME('22:30:21',IFNULL('24:00:00','00:00:00')) as `TOTAL TIME`
```

Comment: Oh god, why didn't I try it before... I only modified your answer and it works. Thank you very much for giving an advice.